# Viewing directory and folders in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have created a directory and folder for keeping the model and checkpoints in amazon sagemaker. How can i access this directory and folder to see model and checkpoints ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running training/serving the endpoint in AWS and not locally, all the files are visible under Amazon S3. Likely when you set up the Sagemaker configuration, you had to create a S3 bucket also.

The other option is that the training runs locally. In that case the files are somewhere in your computer.

When a training job ends, Sagemaker copies the resulting model out of the Docker image to S3 or local computer.

Comment: I cannot see any directory under s3. I specified that temporary directory to store model artifacts. I don't know where my artifacts are stored.

Answer (score 0):

In training, the contents of `/opt/ml/model` are uploaded to the S3 location specified in the `OutputDataConfig` passed when creating the training job.

In hosting and Batch Transform, the S3 location specified by `ModelDataUrl` is unarchived and made available to the inference container at `/opt/ml/model`.

Also see the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-envvariables

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-code-load-artifacts

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-batch-code.html#your-algorithms-batch-code-load-artifacts